# How to use useQuery() for API route parameters in Nuxt 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm following a guide in which `api routes` are built like so:

1 create `server/api/route.js` file:

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {

    return {
        message: `hello api route`
    }
})
```

2 use api route in component like so:

```
<script setup>
const { data: message } = await useFetch('/api/route')
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p>api data {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

This works but when I try to add a `query parameter` in `1.`:

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {

    const { name } = useQuery(event)

    return {
        message: `hello api name parameter ${name}`
    }
})
```

and call it in a component `2.`:

```
<script setup>
const { data: message } = await useFetch('/api/route?name=mario')
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <p>api data {{ message }}</p>
  </div>
</template>
```

the `message` property is empty. It seems that `useQuery(event)` produces an empty variable. Any idea why this is not working?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`useQuery(event)` is no longer supported. You can use `getQuery(event)`

[h3 Docs for getQuery](https://www.jsdocs.io/package/h3#getQuery)

Comment: useBody(event) is also no longer supported.  Replacement is readBody(event)

Answer (score 14):

Try `getQuery` instead of `useQuery`

```
export default defineEventHandler((event) => {
  const { name } = getQuery(event);
  return {
      message: `hello api name parameter ${name}`,
  };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please checkout the docs too:

`useBody(event)` => `readBody(event)`
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#body-handling

`useQuery(event)` => `getQuery(event)`
https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#query-parameters