# Nuxt3 typecsript Error Cannot find name "xxx"

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

[image]

I'm developing with Nuxt3 and have a server route.

Somehow useQuery ends with error. What do I miss here?

`````
  return new Promise<any>((resolve, reject) => {
    (async () => {
      try {
        const cookie = event.req.headers.cookie || "";
        const query = useQuery(event);

        console.log(cookie);
        const res = await fetch(
          "https://auth-xx.westeurope.cloudapp.azure.com/v1/auth/rpc/o2/sessions/whoami",
          { headers: { Accept: "application/json", Cookie: cookie } }
        );
        console.log("data");
        const data = await res.json();
        console.log(data);

        resolve(data);
      } catch (e) {
        reject(e);
      }
    })();
  });
});````
`````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the example in the [docs](https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/server#handling-requests-with-query-parameters):
Try using `getQuery` instead of `useQuery`.

Also, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74522881/12962668) `useQuery` is no longer supported by h3.